# Is the mean of my two time series data significantly different?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, mean

I have two stationary time series and want to know if the mean values are different. One practical application would be there are two motors and I want to know which one needs less energy in average - or I have one motor and make some maintenance work and want to know if the average energy consumption decreased afterwards.

I did some research on the internet but couldn't find a significance test for that case.

Of course the observations of my time series are not independent and I can also chose which sampling rate I want (e.g. 1 minutes intervals or 10 minutes intervals), so I guess a t-test can't be used here.

What would be a correct significance test?

Thanks

Comment: How can it be stationary if the mean is different in two time periods?

Comment: Good point ;) I changed my question.

Comment: Why do you need a significance test?  What actions would you make differently if the difference were not found to be "significant"?

Comment: I expect that the significance test tells me that I have enough data collected so that the different mean values are not by chance. At the moment I can only visualize the time series in boxplots and can decide with gut feeling which mean or median is less. I was hoping that there is a more reliable way that minimize the risk that the difference are there just by chance.